# How do I highlight multiple words in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim, highlighting

There is a cool vim script: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words

I found the script today.
This script is what I want exactly.

It works well with gvim 7.2. (Both of Windows and Linux)
But I wish I can use it on linux shell too. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Is it possible? Or is there another script we can use.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found the alternative script.  
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=479

Comment: Oops, I found another script. I think this is better one.  
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1238

Comment: @Benjamin: where do you put your downloaded scripts?

Comment: @akira Linux, ~/.vim/plugin. Windows, C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin

Comment: @Benjamin: If you found something that answers your question, you can post it as an answer and accept it so others will have an easier time if they have this same issue.

Comment: @Mark: Should I answer at my question? I thought it's illegal.

Comment: @Benjamin: No, it's not illegal. It's fine to answer your own question if you've found something that fixed your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the script.

You can download the script at here.
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666

Just **\m** on the word you want to highlight.
You could select visual block then **\m**
And you could add more colors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with multiple words being highlighted in the same color, simply go to search mode (type `/` in normal mode) and search words that are separated by `\|`

```
/word_1\|word_2\|word_3
```

You can use `n` and `N` to navigate as usual.

Answer (score 0):

put the plugins under `%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles`. maybe put the unixish `.vimrc` to `%USERPROFILE%\_vimrc`.

Comment: Is the path important? I can't understand why do you recommend the path. Please explain more about that.

Comment: "Linux, ~/.vim/plugin. Windows, C:\Program Files\Vim\vimfiles\plugin" ... the path i mentioned is the windows equivalent for the linux one. on linux you put the files in your home, on windows you work on the global folders? bad bad bad behavior.